# Electric flux through gauss law

Tags: electrostatics

Why is it that objects kept in uniform electric field have net flux through them when gauss law says that net flux through a surface is q/epsilon.I mean the net charge will be zero if a gausian surface is drawn so the net flux must also be the same

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law says that the net flux through a *closed* surface is equal to $q/\epsilon_0$ where $q$ is the charge *enclosed* in the surface. Gauss's law would not make sense for open surfaces that don't enclose a volume. For a uniform electric field, any *closed* surface will have equal number of field lines entering the surface as exiting the surface and so the *total* flux across that surface will be 0 as required.

Comment: then why is it that there is a net flux through a disc kept in uniform electric field?

Comment: @MohdKhan Why wouldn't there be? There is a net flux through the disc (assuming it's not being aligned parallel to the field lines), but the disc is not a closed surface and so you can't apply Gauss's law to it.

Comment: As i have been told gaussian surfaces are hypothetical and need not 'come with the body' and can be drawn as per one's convinience.So what if i draw a hypothetical gausian surface enclosing the disc

Comment: 1 more doubt..As per what you have said if the disc has to be a closed surface it becomes a volume..But gauus's law talks about gaussian surfaces

Comment: Gaussian surfaces need to be closed, a disc is not closed. If you drew a *closed* Gaussian surface anywhere (whether it encloses a hypothetical disc or not) you will get a net flux of 0 across the closed surface. Perhaps take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_surface to see an explanation of what a Gaussian surface is.